# Is it possible to WIFI call through a vpn on IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, network, vpn, wifi-calling

So my mobile carrier recently begun supporting WIFI calling for iPhones. After setting it up on my phone, i have found that it does not work at my school. After looking at the protocol list that can be found [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202944) I believe that this may be due to the fact that WIFI calling utilizes IKEv2 which is a very popular VPN protocol, my school maybe blocking it, in an attempt to block access to inappropriate websites. I have already tried using VPNs such as [hotspot shield](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hotspotshield-vpn-wifi-proxy/id443369807?mt=8) and shadowsocks to no avail.

So to summarize my problem: how can i force WIFI calling to utilize my VPN?

As a side note, I have already verified the functionality of WIFI calling by turning my phone on airplane mode at a nearby coffee shop, and it operated without a problem.

Comment: What’s your question? As it’s written it seems like “my school blocked the vpn how do I get around there block”

Comment: @Josh my school blocks some common vpn protocols, such as the one wifi calling uses. I am asking if i can force WIFI-Calling to tunnel through a vpn which works at school. thanks in advance

Comment: What VPN or VPN protocol does work? And do you want WiFi calling to use a different protocol or want to use the same protocol but through a VPN?

Comment: @Josh I have found that Hotspot shields "proprietary protocol" and shadowsocks running on a vps i rent using the Potatso Lite client both get around the school block effectively.

Comment: Do you want WiFi calling to use a different protocol or want to use the same protocol but through a VPN?

Comment: @josh, i do not believe that WIFI calling is capable of utilizing a different protocol. especially since it would require support by my mobile carrier. I was hoping for WIFI calling to use the same protocol but through a vpn.

Comment: You are correct, it is most likely not capable. Just making sure.

Comment: @Josh if i jailbreak my phone, do you know of any vpn client capable of doing what i want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78861/discussion-between-josh-and-mohammad-ali).